# Is there a typo in the formula or does my GAP-package sglppow fail?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, conjectures, gap, groups-enumeration

This [site](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Higman's_PORC_conjecture)
deals with group formulas for prime powers $p^k$ for $k\le 7$. The
formula for $k=7$ seems to be wrong.

I compared the results with GAP and
the formula is off by $2453$ for $p=13,17,19,23$ and $29$.

Moreover the
lcm of the numbers $3,4,5,7,8,9$ is not $360$, but $2520$ and as I understood
the column "modulus relative ...", the value $2520$ should be right.

The values for $p=7$ and $p=11$ coincide with the given formula.

> Does anyone know the correct formula ? Does GAP give the wrong values, or is the given formula wrong ?

The formula given in the link is

$$gnu(p^7)=3p^5+12p^4+44p^3+170p^2+707p+2455$$
$$+(4p^2+44p+291)gcd(p-1,3)+(p^2+19p+135)gcd(p-1,4)$$
$$+(3p+31)gcd(p-1,5)+4gcd(p-1,7)+5gcd(p-1,8)+gcd(p-1,9)$$

What I get with GAP :

```
gap> LoadPackage("sglppow");
LieRing
a package for working with Lie rings 
by Serena Cicalo' and Willem de Graaf
----------------------------------------------------------------
Loading  LiePRing 1.8
by Michael Vaughan-Lee and Bettina Eick 
----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
Loading SglPPow 1.0
by Michael Vaughan-Lee and Bettina Eick 
----------------------------------------------------------------
true
gap> gnup7:=p->3*p^5+12*p^4+44*p^3+170*p^2+707*p+2455+
> (4*p^2+44*p+291)*Gcd(p-1,3)+(p^2+19*p+135)*Gcd(p-1,4)+
> (3*p+31)*Gcd(p-1,5)+4*Gcd(p-1,7)+5*Gcd(p-1,8)+Gcd(p-1,9);
function( p ) ... end
gap> p:=Filtered([7..100],IsPrimeInt);
[ 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 
  83, 89, 97 ]
gap> r:=List( p, x -> [ x, gnup7(x), NrSmallGroups(x^7) ] );
[ [ 7, 113147, 113147 ], [ 11, 750735, 750735 ], [ 13, 1600573, 1598120 ], 
  [ 17, 5546909, 5544456 ], [ 19, 9380741, 9378288 ], 
  [ 23, 23316851, 23314398 ], [ 29, 71271069, 71268616 ], 
  [ 31, 98488755, 98486302 ], [ 37, 233043067, 233040614 ], 
  [ 41, 384847485, 384845032 ], [ 43, 485930975, 485928522 ], 
  [ 47, 751588475, 751586022 ], [ 53, 1356370173, 1356367720 ], 
  [ 59, 2299880351, 2299877898 ], [ 61, 2710679045, 2710676592 ], 
  [ 67, 4306310927, 4306308474 ], [ 71, 5734323819, 5734321366 ], 
  [ 73, 6578172579, 6578170126 ], [ 79, 9721485395, 9721482942 ], 
  [ 83, 12413061671, 12413059218 ], [ 89, 17537591045, 17537588592 ], 
  [ 97, 26866372821, 26866370368 ] ]
gap> List(r, x -> [x[2]-x[3]]);
[ [ 0 ], [ 0 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], 
  [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], 
  [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ], [ 2453 ] ]
gap>
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the people who keep that site?

Comment: May I suggest to improve this question? Would be nice to have more informative title, and make it more-self containing - instead of referring to an external site that may change in the future, give the formula for $k=7$ here, and show your GAP calculations. If you think that this is an error in GAP, follow @ahulpke's advice how to report it.

Comment: Maybe you detect a missing package ; I displayed the complete output.

Comment: Thanks. Note that the formula is for $p>5$, so no need to use smaller $p$. I've edited GAP session to give a complete example - yes, I see the offset of 2453 for $p>11$.

Comment: I do not think that this number is obtained from the `sglppow` package, but is already part of the small groups library (can you try without the package?). Also, the constant in the polynomial is $2455$ while you notice a discrepancy of $2453$. I am willing to bet that a file got corrupted (namely the $455$-bit is missing). Identifying and debugging this might not be of interest to the general math.stackexchange audience -- I suggest you email me privately (hulpke@math.colostate.edu) and I can send you commands to help in identifying what is happening.

Comment: @hulpke: sglppow gives access to the groups of order $p^7$ for $p>11$ (and to the groups of order $3^8$) and extends the range of applicability of  `NrSmallGroups` (see [manual](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/sglppow/doc/manual.pdf)). But $13^7$ and $17^7$ are also provided by the Small Groups Library, so there is an overlap. Like your idea of the bet on 455 :)

Comment: @Peter: You may look how sglppow calculates the numbers in `sglppow/lib/phoch7/sgl-p7.g` and fix the formula that it uses. I've reported the problem to package authors - thanks for discovering this.

Comment: You can now download sglppow 1.1 from http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/~beick/soft/sglppow/ - it corrects the typo. The new version should appear in the next GAP release.

Comment: So, the only error in tha table is the entry $360$ in the third column, or do I miss something ? I think it should be $lcm(3,4,5,7,8,9)=2520$

Comment: Another weird thing : I got the following output by calculating $gnu(p^6)$ : 42209:5346445608
42221:5349485564
42223:5349992324
42227:5351005832
42239:5354047076
gap: cannot extend the workspace any more!
gap: Press <Enter> to end program

Comment: Does that mean that the package only uses the formula for $p^7$ ? If it would use the formula for $p^6$, why the error ?

Comment: @Peter `NrSmallGroups` uses another formula for $p^6$. The way this is implemented is that not just counts, but also calculating formulas and supporting data are cached internally, in a list at position group order. If you form p^6 for huge primes this produces a gigantic list which uses up memory -- thus the error message. I wonder whether for your purposes it might be sufficient to simply take the PORC polynomial for $p^6$, replace each GCD by its maximum value, and then work with this polynomial.

Comment: I tested NrSmallGroup(p^7) with a $20$-digit prime, no problem, but NrSmallGroup(p^6) with the sam prime gives an error. But you are right, I simply can take the given formula and everything is alright ...

Comment: There is no need to replace the gcd-functions, it is no problem to implement the given formula, if you mean that.

Comment: @Peter I thought about replacing the GCD to make it easier to estimate asymptotically.

Comment: Yes, I have done this because I wanted to know which prime powers are group-abundant ($gnu(p^k)>p^k$)  (or even group-perfect ($gnu(p^k)=p^k$)).

Comment: And the result : For $p>3$ and $k\le 7$, there are no group-perfect prime powers and the only group-abundant prime powers are $2^5,2^6,2^7$ and $3^7$. Furthermore, $2^8$ and $3^8$ are group-abundant. It would be an interesting question, whether all prime powers $p^k$ with $k\ge 8$, are group-abundant or not.

Answer (score 6):

The formula on the web page you cite comes from a paper by O'Brien and Vaughan-Lee that classified the groups of order $p^7$. Web page and paper agree on the formula.

The formula gives 1600573 groups of order $13^7$ and $5546909$ groups of order $17^7$. Exactly the same numbers are given by `NrSmallGroups` in GAP (without special packages). I can only conclude that no discrepancy exists and that the formula is correct.

If you get reproducibly wrong numbers with a current, clean, installation of GAP, please send an error description to gap@gap-system.org, including version number, system information, and the compiler you used.

Followup -- for the record as this is the only answer: It seems the `sglppow' package had a misprint in the implementation of this formula -- this bug will be corrected.

Comment: The new release of SglPPow, version 1.1 was picked up on 22/01/16 and became available since GAP 4.8.2, so the typo is now corrected. You may check at http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sglppow.html that the version is 1.1. The release date is older (it is taken from the PackageInfo.g file, so can not be fixed on autogenerated pages), so that that may cause a confusion, but the fix is there (Note: it always helps to state version of the GAP and relevant packages when reporting a bug. GAP distribution never has different content of core system or of any package with the same version number).